# Continue For in using block

Tags: vb.net

Will this `continue for` command dispose the object that's being used? In this case the object I mentioned is the `con` connection

```
For Each x in y 
    Using con As connection = createconnection()
        ' blah blah 
        If "some condition" Then
            Continue For 
        End if
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Yes, it will.  Of course, why don't you run the code and find out?

Comment: Thanks, I did run the code but I'm still not very sure so I need to hear it from someone like you :D. Please post your comment as the answer @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will.  (Or at the very least, it *really should*.)  A `Using` block is essentially a `Try/Finally` construct which calls `Dispose()` in the `Finally`.  Any time control leaves the block, it executes the `Finally`.

Consider it essentially the same thing as this:

```
For Each x in y 
    Dim con As connection = createconnection()
    Try
        ' blah blah 
        If "some condition" Then
            Continue For 
        End if
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
Next
```

Before the loop can iterate again, control has to leave the `Try` block.  Which triggers the `Finally`.

The only thing you'd want to watch out for is if `con` exists outside the scope of this block.  An object is disposed, but it still *exists* in a disposed state if something has a reference to it.  There's nothing in the language that would prevent you from using an existing object in a `Using` construct, you'd just want to be careful that nothing else tries to use it after it's disposed.